# Execute command with backquote in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I write up a little shell script in bash that allows me to execute commands in sub-directories. Here is the script

bat.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in */; do
  echo "Executing \"$@\" in $d"
  cd $d
  `$@`
  cd ..
done
```

With my following directory structures

```
/home/user
--a/
----x.txt
----y.txt
--b/
----u.txt
----v.txt
```

I expect the following command to list out the content of directories a and b when it is executed in the home directory
    bat.sh ls

The result is

```
Executing "ls" in a/
/home/user/bin/bat.sh: line 6: x.txt: command not found
Executing "ls" in b/
/home/user/bin/bat.sh: line 6: u.txt: command not found
```

Any idea on what is going wrong here?

Comment: Txt files aren't executables... what do you expect the result of executing `x.txt` to be?

Comment: Drop those backticks, and quote `$@`: `"$@"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the back quotes; you want double quotes.

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in */
do
    echo "Executing \"$*\" in $d"
    (cd "$d" && "$@")
done
```

You are trying to execute the output of the command you pass, whereas you simply want to execute the command.

The use of an explicit subshell (the `( … )` notation) may avoid some problems with symlinks that jump to other directories.  It is, in my (perhaps archaic) view, a safer way to switch directories for the purposes of executing commands.

Comment: In this case, the missing quotes really are critical -- directories with spaces in their names are a thing that happen.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes; this time you're correct (but I was copying the code from the question which mostly worked).  It is also an opportunity to legitimately use `$*` inside the double quotes, but maybe that's a bit subtle.

Comment: (Might also be good practice to make it `cd "$d" && "$@"`, to ensure that a failure in the `cd` doesn't result in running the wrapped command in the current directory; preferring graceful failure modes, &c).

Comment: Now that we are on the topic, Please check this answer: [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17529221/793796) Section "Execute output of a command". I have commented on that answer; but did not receive any satisfactory answer...